# Terraform Cloud workspace structure

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

I am pretty new to Terraform and Terraform Cloud and I'm looking at the best way to structure my Terraform Cloud Workspaces.

Use Case: Relatively simple webapp, RDS, ECS/Fargate etc

I am currently evaluating with the following workspaces:

1. ECR
2. Database
3. AppCore (ECS Cluster, ALB, etc etc)
4. ECS Service/Tasks

Benefits: Small blast radius, logical chunks, can use Terraform when updating to new ECS task definitions.

I thought I found a doc on Terraforms site that suggested breaking workspaces similar to this was their recommended approach but I can't seem to find it again at the moment.

Is this good? bad? I've heard putting all your infrastructure in a single workspace can make things painful later.

Any ideas, thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would use use workspaces for that? You usually use them to separate your dev, prod and test environemnts, not to fragment your config into smaller ones.

Comment: This is the link to the Terraform docs recommending this type of approach.  https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/guides/recommended-practices/part1.html#one-workspace-per-environment-per-terraform-configuration

Comment: I see. If you fragment your self too much you will be just constantly changing workspaces. So you have to find balance for your app.

Comment: Yep, agree balance is key. Interested in peoples experiences in doing this and what they found to be a good balance for them and why.